# How to resolve broadcasted variable issues in parloop?

Tags: matlab

I have made for loop parralel in matlab, but I get warning that some of my arrays are broadcasted which lead to unnecessary communication overhead. I'm new in matlab and don't know how to solve this issue. Would someone help me with this?
`A` and `Y` is broadcasted in this code

```
parfor k=1:length(gamma)

    Lambda=gamma(k);
    tmp=zeros(nfolds,Num_Tasks);

    for p=1:length(omega)

        OmegA= omega(p)
        for Fold=1:size(Fold_indices,2)
            % Creat train and test fold
            A_Train=A(logical(Fold_indices(:,Fold)),1:end);  # A is broadcasted
            %size(A_Train)
            Y_Train=Y(logical(Fold_indices(:,Fold)),1:Num_Tasks); # Y is broadcated

            A_Test=A(~logical(Fold_indices(:,Fold)),1:end);
            Y_Test=Y(~logical(Fold_indices(:,Fold)),1:Num_Tasks);
            coff=Estimate_x(Y_Train,A_Train,Lambda,OmegA,Binding_matrix)  ;


            % Do the prediction on Kth f;old and compute the error
            % coff
            %sum((A_Test*coff-Y_Test).^2) ./ size(A_Test,1)
            tmp(Fold,1:end)=sum((A_Test*coff-Y_Test).^2) ./ size(A_Test,1);
            tmp;
            %Coefficents{:,Fold}=coff;
            coff
        end
        In_Fold_Error{1,p}=tmp;
        %In_Fold_Error{2,k}= Lambda;


        Coefficents{:,p}=coff;
    end
    CVErr_twoparam{1,k}=In_Fold_Error;
    Coefficents_twoparam=Coefficents;

end
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the exact error message or warning (verbatim)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can compute `A_Train` and `Y_Train` directly in the `parfor` loop, as opposed to using subscripting in order to get their values from `A` and `Y`, there's nothing you can do. Your source of information is unique, so these values will be broadcasted.

If you have enough memory, maybe it would be a better idea to compute `A_Train` and `Y_Train` as cell arrays of matrices in a normal `for`, and then use these sequentially pre-computed values inside the `parfor`. Like this you don't send the entire matrices `A` and `Y` to workers.